# Self Answering Puzzles

Tags: riddle, language

Give the right guess in an English sentence self answering puzzle offer that contains eighty four words, one hundred and nineteen syllables, ten As, two Bs, five Cs, seven Ds, fifty nine Es, fifteen Fs, nine Gs, fourteen Hs, twenty one Is, one J, one K, seven Ls, three Ms, forty Ns, nineteen Os, four Ps, one Q, seventeen Rs, forty Ss, thirty Ts, seven Us, eight Vs, five Ws, one X, ten Ys, three Zs, thirty commas, eighty three spaces, and one period.

Edit:  I originally posted "Post other self answering puzzles," but this makes this entry very broad and against forum rules.  However, the above puzzle has a very specific answer that is given by ABcDexter below.

Comment: Are you just asking for us to come up with [autograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogram)?

Comment: @Will In the same family as the autogram and the [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), but slightly different, I think: a puzzle that is it's own solution. either a question that answers itself, or a command that satisfies itself.

Comment: @Will, as mentioned by Peter, I am asking for a puzzle that is its own solution.  For example, the sentence "this sentence has five words," is an autogram, but it's not a self answering puzzle/request.  The sentence "give a sentence that has seven words," is its own solution.  The puzzle has to make some request that the puzzle itself fulfills such that one could just give the puzzle back as a solution.

Comment: This is definitely *way* too broad.

Comment: Perhaps you meant: "T h i s   i s   w a y   t o o   b r o a d ."

Answer (score 15):

Which question formed an answer on this page that received 15 upvotes?

Comment: Come on guys, don't let me down.

Comment: Think I'll wait to see 14 or 15 votes before deciding (just kidding, but if this gets edited I can change my ^vote so far)

Comment: Why not 15+ upvotes?

Comment: I like this answer, but if I upvote it it will be wrong and I won't like it any more

Comment: Only 15? Come on, there would have been room for a bit more ambition!

Comment: Hehe, now it is wrong. >:D

Comment: Some of upvoters still have time to reverse the vote (at least one already did).

Comment: *sigh* I wish I could downvote this answer. It's at 16!

Comment: No edits, people :) That would be cheating.

Comment: Downvoted so that the answer would be correct.

Comment: I'm so sorry. +1

Comment: didn't thought I would say that but: nice answer, -1!

Answer (score 11):

The

> paragraph itself.
>  Give the right guess in an English sentence self answering puzzle offer that contains eighty four words, one hundred and nineteen syllables, ten As, two Bs, five Cs, seven Ds, fifty nine Es, fifteen Fs, nine Gs, fourteen Hs, twenty one Is, one J, one K, seven Ls, three Ms, forty Ns, nineteen Os, four Ps, one Q, seventeen Rs, forty Ss, thirty Ts, seven Us, eight Vs, five Ws, one X, ten Ys, three Zs, thirty commas, eighty three spaces, and one period.

is the answer.

Let me write a [code for that](http://ideone.com/6egXaR). will update soon...

```
//ABcDexter, puzzling.SE,q/37303/1766, 10/7/16 1211
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int i,n,t;
string inp;
int count[26]={0};

int main()
{   

//cin>>inp;
char ch;
int words=0,commas=0,spaces=0,periods=0; 


for(i=0; (ch=getchar()) && (ch!='\n'); i++) 
{   
    inp+=ch;//cout<<ch;
    switch(ch)
    { 
        case ' ' : words++,spaces++;
                break;
        case ',': commas++;
                break;
        case '.': periods++;
                break;
        default: //cout<<inp[i];
                if(inp[i]>='a' && inp[i]<='z') ::count[inp[i]-'a']++;
                else if(inp[i]>='A' && inp[i]<='Z') ::count[inp[i]-'A']++;

    }
}

cout<<"Here is the count\n";
cout<<"Number of words : "<<++words<<endl; //words+1 as one more for the final word with no space at the end;
for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    cout<<"count of "<<char(i+65)<<" "<<::count[i]<<endl;

cout<<"Number of commas : "<<commas<<endl;
cout<<"Number of spaces : "<<spaces<<endl;
cout<<"Number of periods : "<<periods<<"\nsorry, don't know how to count syllables"<<endl; 



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is one that relies on the absence of explicit punctuation (so either directly lacking punctuation when written, as below, or speaking the puzzle out loud).

> What is the most commonly used interrogative word in the English language

Comment: That is interesting :)

Comment: @ABcDexter - it's worth noting that I'm assuming it to be true. It's hard to confirm it with any confidence, but given that it's often used in place of "pardon" by most children (and probably most adults), I'm pretty confident of its accuracy.

Comment: Why is the most common interrogative not what [punctuation removed, ^vote added]

Answer (score 6):

> Which is the most self-answering puzzle?

Comment: Vote of approval in case this turns out to be the most self-answering puzzle while I'm not looking

Answer (score 5):

Is this one?

> Provide a self-answering puzzle.

Paradox time!

> Provide a puzzle that is not self-answering.

Comment: Vote of approval for the fun ideas.
(The first one _could_ be assigned a truth value of false, though, without contradiction.)

Answer (score 5):

> Provide proof that this sentence exists.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you provide a question that asks you to provide a question that asks you to provide a question?

Answer (score 3):

Just a smarty-pants alternate *guess* in case
[ABcDexter's
 likely-correct answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/37304/18129)
isn't the “right guess”:

> Give the right guess in **one [swapped]** English sentence
>  self answering puzzle offer that contains
>  eighty four words,
>  one hundred and nineteen syllables,
>  ten As,
>  two Bs,
>  five Cs,
>  seven Ds,
>  fifty nine Es,
>  fifteen Fs,
>  nine Gs,
>  fourteen Hs,
>  twenty one Is,
>  one J,
>  one K,
>  seven Ls,
>  three Ms,
>  forty Ns,
>  nineteen Os,
>  four Ps,
>  one Q,
>  seventeen Rs,
>  forty Ss,
>  thirty Ts,
>  seven Us,
>  eight Vs,
>  five Ws,
>  **an [swapped]** X,
>  ten Ys,
>  three Zs,
>  thirty commas **[“commas” contains a “comma”]**,
>  eighty three spaces
>  **[[discretionary comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) removed]**
>  and one period.

Comment: Ooops, this has extra "period" after all.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> Who's on first (?/.)

Sorry. :)

Answer (score 2):

Which question resulted only seven answers where the last answer was accepted and had the maximum votes?

Comment: Sorry to be nitpicky, but the solution to this puzzle is the question at the top of the page, not your puzzle itself.

Answer (score 1):

Which question answer is this?